# React router push to history and preserve relative path

Tags: react-router

I am using react router and I have the following code:

```
let history = useHistory();

let goToReviewPage = () => history.push(`review/${productId}`);
```

My current url is: `/foo/bar` and calling `goToReviewPage()` will redirect me to

`/foo/review/${productId}` instead of `/foo/bar/review/${productId}`

I am not sure how to set the base path will pushing the history.

Comment: I am doing something similar but using react-cookies to store history. Have you tried - `history.push(`bar/review/${productId}`);` ?

Comment: Of course I can say `history.push(`/foo/bar/review/${productId}`)`, but I want the react router to be more flexible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to use `window.location` to obtain the current path.

For example:

```
history.push(window.location.pathname + '/' + `review/${productId}`);
```

[**window.location api**](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp)

Answer (score 7):

You can use React Router's `match.url`. Example:

```
const Component = ({ productId }) => {
  const match = useRouteMatch();
  const history = useHistory();

  const handleClick = () => {
    history.push(`${match.url}/review/${productId}`);
  };

  return (
    <button onClick={handleClick}>Click me</button>
  );
};
```